# Jmeter defining Throughput

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

Yes i have six months experiences with Jmeter and i have a learned a lot, but not all. Now i have faces with problem from management. They need too see a throughput for each action for one test case.
Test case:

```
- Log In (get loginID)
- call service for creating data( with Loginid)
- call service for creating data1( with Loginid)
```

expected result:
Login: 2 logins per second ( response take from 400 ms to 670 ms)
Call service: should be executed for 100 times per second ( from 30 ms up to 60 ms).
loop for call service 10 times.

Test case in jmeter:

```
Thread Group
  - Transaction controler #1
     -- Login
     -- Throughput Shapring timer ( Start RPS=2, END RPS=2, Duration=1)
  - Transaction controler #2
     -- Function generate random data for service1 and service2
     -- Loop  10 times
       --- call service1 for update table 1
       --- call service2 for update table 2
     -- Throughput Shaping timer ( Start RPS=100, END RPS=100, Duration=1)
```

Execution of the test:
Treads: 100 Users
Rampup period: 100 seconds
Duration: 900 seconds

> Transaction controler #1 In the transaction per second is average 2
>   transaction per second
>
> Transaction controler #2 In the transaction per second is average 100
>   transaction per second

Is this done in correct way or i miss something?

Thank you for support and advise.

Regards

Comment: First of all can you please tell that why you have selected transaction controller for your load tests?

Comment: I selected a transaction cotroler to avoid throughput for each transaction controler, should i use different controller?

Comment: Its fine but if you want to measure real performance of each server like :- Log In 
- call service for creating data
- call service for creating data1  - then you should put load on each page/service. All depends on your objective of performance testing.

Comment: If i want to change data in service i need to be login to get loginId, and with this loginid i can able to change data, this make sense? Will thoughput have diffenrent values when test case is run on more servers ( distributed run)?

Comment: In real life scenario in case of multiple requests throughput for each request separately will not be useful. Reason is you cannot be sure that server is processing only 1 type of request at a time. Server can be processing login,call service at the same time. both of them can have their impacts on each other. thus deviation in actual throughput. what you can be sure about in such scenarios is average throughput for x no. of users. If you want throughput for single request (IMHO Which is not much useful) then load your server with only type of request at a given time i.e. login or call service

Comment: @Nachiket Kate - Thank you for advice and support.This is a life scenario, one player can login , another user is calling service1 and another is calling service. Calling service (update table) without login will not work. In real scenario this actions really happens. I have done also test s for single requests login, login once and call services. Sorry i'm little bit confused because maybe i do not understand you what you mean to tell me because i what i'm thinking about, what did i miss?

Comment: @Nachiket Kate - Throughput can be measured with different graphs with jp@gc - Graphs Generator to include or exclude samplers. This show a real responses under load testing, isn't?

Comment: Its correct that for calling a service you need to login first but what I meant is in such cases you can rely on average throughput and not per request throughput(reason in first comment). If you want to find out throughput for each req. then load test with each request seperately. I agree its not possible everytime. in your case you can measure throughput for call service like, 100 users login in 2 min. after login each user waits for 2 min to finish all the users login process. and then start service call1 for all users. This way you can get throughput for only call service or login.

Comment: I hope you get it this time.

Comment: @Nachiket Kate - Thank you, now i understand :). How should be this done, in what way you described, should please give me a short directions, i do not have an idea how to made a test case ?

Comment: Do you want me to write answer?

Comment: Yes ,please, only actions, because i do not know how100 threads login and wait until all are completed and then going to call service.